# If a VFD-driven induction motor can be operated as a generator, what will be the voltage and frequency of the generated voltage?

Tags: generator, induction-motor, vfd

It is known that when an induction generator is connected to the grid, the frequency and voltage of the electricity generated will be that of the grid  but when the VFD is connected inbetween grid and induction generator, what will happen to the frequency and voltage of the generated voltage?

Answer (score 2):

We're talking AC generators here. For simplicitys sake I'll assume synchronous generators with permanent magnets.

In most generator designs the output voltage is a function of the rotation speed. The higher the rotation speed, the higher the voltage. So grid connected generators are designed in a way that they generate the requidred volate (often around 10kV) when the rotation speed matches the line frequency (often 1500 rpm for 50Hz, 1800 rpm for 60 Hz systems). Behind the generator there are transformers which will transform the generated voltage to the transport grid voltage (often in the range between 55kV and 400kV). Often (always?) those transformers are adjustable. The amount of power given to the grid is a function of the phase shift between the generator and the grid. If the generator is "in front" of the grid, it will push energy into the grid...

The torque needed to keep the generator moving is a function of the load (current). The higher the current, the more torque is needed to turn the generator.

So voltage, current, phase angle... everything is closely coupled by physics in a directly connected system.

Now add a VFD: Now the VFD will make sure that phase and voltage match on the grid side. The generator can basically just run at "any speed". This is usefull for system where the energy source would have a hard time keeping the rpm constant (for example in wind turbines). Now the VFD will take whatever voltage and frequency it is getting from the generator, convert it to DC and convert that DC to the required AC voltage and frequency to be given to the grid. Normally, VFD of this kind do [MPPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) on the generator side to get the maximum power out of your generator.

But the simple formula is: U = f(rpm). Sure, due to resistive losses, the voltage will drop a bit if the load on the generator increases. But for simplicity sake, let's ignore that :)

Comment: thnaks for the reply...  you mean to say even if frequency of generated voltage is different   it will be ultimately converted to DC and then this DC is converted to required AC voltage and frequency to be given to grid...is that right

Comment: @user133896 it will only be sent back into the AC grid if the VFD is an expensive one designed to do that. A normal 'drive the motor only' VFD will see its internal DC bus rise. What happens next? You or it might load the DC bus with a braking resistor. You might load the DC bus with your battery charger. It might disconnect the motor to avoid failing. Or the DC rise might continue until it damages the VFD.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks for the reply... how we do charging of battery using DC link.. will not the input DC power (from grid) also  start charging of battery instead of generated power form induction motor.  is there any design document related to this?

Comment: If the VFD uses a simple bridge rectifier from the mains (unlikely due to power factor requirements these days), then the simple rising of the DC bus voltage will stop power delivery from the grid. If the input is via a power factor corrected boost converter, then the rise in DC bus voltage should automatically shut the boost converter down via its control loop.

Answer (score 2):

Typical VFDs have a bridge rectifier on the input. These provide a one-way conversion of AC to DC for the internal DC-link. It is not possible to convert the DC back to AC for backfeed into the grid unless the VFD has been specifically designed with that in mind.

If you are asking what happens during deceleration of a VFD induction motor then the answer is that it will regenerate into the VFD's DC-link. The DC-link voltage will then rise. If there is a brake resistor then at some point the VFD will dump the excess voltage into the resistor to avoid an overvoltage on the DC-link. If there is no resistor then the motor will be disconnected to prevent further regeneration and voltage rise.

Comment: thanks for the reply...    can use this generated energy to charge battery instead of dissipating it in resistance. is it possible?  by doing that energy could be saved instead of dissipating it as heat....

Comment: Anything is possible but it may not be economical. Batteries are tricky to charge and have a limited life, additional maintenance cost and take up space.